# When is this function continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Our codomain is the metric space $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ - the set of all functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ - endowed with the $L^1$ metric.

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [\underline{y},\overline{y}]$ be a continuous function which has no "flat regions". My question is: Is the function $\mathbf{1}(f(x) \geq y)$ continuous in $y$ for $y \in (\underline{y},\overline{y}]$?

My approach: I think I have been able to show this when $f$ is "nice", say when $[0,1]$ can be partitioned into a finite no. of intervals such that $f$ is neither strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in each interval. But $f$ can be oscillating (e.g. $x sin \frac{1}{x}$), and I'm not sure if the function described above is continuous on $[\underline{y},\overline{y}]$ in that case.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no such thing as $L^{1}$ metric defined for all functions from $[0,1]$ to itself.

Comment: Thank you! OK maybe I'm making  mistake (I'm a beginner in fn.al analysis as you can tell) - can you suggest what would be the right metric to use for this problem? I need to prove something about path connectedness of a subset of that space, so that's why I need a metric.