# Why can't the $L_1$ metric be used in this space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, connectedness

I'm trying to prove that a certain given subset of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is path connected. For this I'm trying to find continuous functions $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^{[0,1]}$. My confusion is, for that we need to use some metric on $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$. What is the right metric for this particular purpose? I thought I could use $L_1$ but a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490154/when-is-this-function-continuous) (a related question I posted earlier) says it can't be used. I could not understand why. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: The $L_1$ metric cannot be used because not all functions are integrable.  One alternative is to restrict to the subset of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ formed by the integrable functions.  If that is not satisfactory, the most natural topology on $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is the product topology.

Comment: @Ruy is correct. The problem is that not every function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is measurable.

Comment: Unfortunately I realized my set does have non-integrable functions. My set can be partitioned as $D=D_1 U D_2$ where $D_1$ contains no non-integrable functions. And $D_2$ contains them but is convex, so path connected. Now I can take the integrable subset of $D$ and show this is path connected, endowing it with the L1 norm. Is this sufficient? I'm not at all familiar with topology, though reasonably comfortable with analysis using metric spaces, so I'm trying to  avoid using product topology if possible. Thank you so much for your help.